# Remove trailing zeros in auto-generated data tables

Tags: tables, siunitx, decimal-number

I am using Siunitx for an auto-generated table (Stata). I wish to remove trailing zeros.
For instance, in the following MWE I want the "Min" Column to be 0 and 1. instead of 0.00 and 1.00.

[image]
MWE:

```
%:Class
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
   %:begin
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\caption{Descriptive Statistics}
\begin{tabular*}{\hsize}{@{\hskip\tabcolsep\extracolsep\fill}ls[table-format=5.0,table-text-alignment=left]*{4}{S[table-format=1.3]}}
                    &         {N}&      {Mean}&      {S.D.}&       {Min}&       {Max}\\
A              &     463,777&        0.51&        0.50&        0.00&        1.00\\
B           &     453,133&        1.15&        0.48&        1.00&        3.00\\
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of `round-mode=places, round-precision=0` you can round toe numbers accordingly:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
   %:begin
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\sisetup{input-ignore={,}, input-decimal-markers = {.}, group-separator={,}}
\caption{Descriptive Statistics}
\begin{tabular*}{\hsize}{@{\hskip\tabcolsep\extracolsep\fill}
                         l
                         S[table-format=6]
                         *{2}{S[table-format=1.3]}
                         *{2}{S[table-format=1, round-mode=places, round-precision=0]}}
   &         {N} &      {Mean} &      {S.D.} &       {Min} &       {Max} \\
A  &     463,777 &        0.51 &        0.50 &        0.00 &        1.00 \\
B  &     453,133 &        1.15 &        0.48 &        1.00 &        3.00 \\
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```